# React Router update subcomponent upon route push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a component like this

```
class myApp extends React.Component {
  return (
   <div>
     <NavigationBar />
     {/* dynamic_content */}
   </div> )
}
```

with this route

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/" component={myApp}/>
</Router>
```

And it loads fine. 
What I'd like to achieve is that when the url changes, for example

```
/profile
/notifications
```

the `dynamic_content` is updated, without actually transitioning to another component. 
In pseudocode what I want is like

```
class myApp extends React.Component {
  return (
   <div>
     <NavigationBar />
     {route === '/profile' -> <Profile/>
      route === '/notification' -> <Notification/>}
   </div> )
```

is this even possible? 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, what you need is to define nested Routes like

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  return (
   <div>
     <NavigationBar />
     {/* dynamic_content */}
     <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
     <Route path="/notification" component={Notification}/>
   </div> )
}
```

and configure your Parent route without a `exact` props

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={MyApp}/>
</Router>
```

Also you must define your components with UpperCase character as the first letter